# ¿Por qué el TextArea no escribe donde debe?

Tags: java, java-swing, jframe, jpanel

He recreado el fallo de un programa mayor en uno más sencillo. Así pues, supongamos las **cuatro clases** siguientes:

(1) Para crear el **marco** o ventana:

```
public class Marco2 extends JFrame{
    
    public Marco2() {
        setSize(800,600);
        setResizable(false);
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setLocation(200,200);
        Lamina2 lamina = new Lamina2();
        add(lamina);
    }
}
```

(2) Para crear la **lámina** o panel:

```
public class Lamina2 extends JPanel implements ActionListener{
    
    private JTextArea casilla;
    
    public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        casilla = new JTextArea();
        casilla.setBounds(592, 95, 177, 400);
        add(casilla);

        JButton boton = new JButton("EJECUTAR");
        boton.setBounds(592, 65, 177, 20);
        add(boton);
        boton.addActionListener(this);
    }

    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        Algoritmo2 alg = new Algoritmo2();
        alg.algoritmo(casilla);
    }
    
}
```

(3) El **algoritmo** a ejecutar:

```
public class Algoritmo2 {
    public void algoritmo(JTextArea casilla) {
        String resultado = "Hola\nMundo";
        casilla.setText(resultado);
    }
}
```

(4) El **ejecutable**:

```
public class Ejecutable2 {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Marco2 miMarco = new Marco2();
        miMarco.setVisible(true);
    }
    
}
```

Todas las clases son del mismo paquete y tienen todo lo necesario importado. Al ejecutar el programa, sale esto:

[image: ventana1]

Se trata de una ventana vacía: solo tiene el **textArea situado a la derecha y el botón EJECUTAR justo encima**. Al pulsar dicho botón, sucede lo siguiente:

[image: ventana2]

**No escribe en el área definida**, sino arriba y centrado. ¿Por qué? Gracias.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El problema me parece que está en que sobreescribiste el método [`paintComponent(Graphics)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JComponent.html#printComponent(java.awt.Graphics)), el cual va a ser invocado cuando se "repinte" la interfaz, que sucede cuando le das click al botón.

Te recomiendo revisar [este](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/painting/summary.html) tutorial de Oracle sobre `paint()` y `paintComponent(Graphics)`.

*No escribe en el área definida, sino arriba y centrado. ¿Por qué?*

Esa es una pregunta interesante. Lo que sucede es que el `paintComponent()` se invoca varias veces (y/o diste varias veces click en el botón), contarlas específicamente no me es fácil, no soy experto de java swing. Pero lo que sí te puedo decir es que internamente cuando hay una acción que requiere que el componente actualice su visualización, el padre invoca a `paint()` y/o `repaint()` que a su vez invocan (entre otros métodos) a `paintComponent()`, y eso hace que veas repetidos los botones y los text area. Esto probablemente lo puedes ver mejor si intentas hacer **gradualmente** la ventana más grande o pequeña. La vista del componente se debe actualizar cuando haces esto, lo que resultará en varias llamadas a `paintComponent()`.

Respecto a porqué no aparece donde quieres tiene que ver con que en `paintComponent()` estás creando nuevamente el text area que tenías antes y más aún la referencia del anterior la estás reemplazando con el nuevo (ojo: esto en lenguajes sin GC sería un memory leak, java tiene GC y en este caso no es muy "importante", pero eso no quiere decir que no nos preocupemos por el manejo de memoria). Eso y la secuencia en que se ejecuta la actualización de la vista y la escritura en el text area, te dan el comportamiento que dices: *no escribe en el área definida, sino arriba y centrado*.

Una forma de arreglarlo es simplemente no agregar los componentes adentro de `paintComponents()`. El creador de GUI de Netbeans lo hace en el método `initComponents()`

```
public class Lamina2 extends JPanel implements ActionListener {
    private JTextArea casilla;

    public Lamina2() {
        super(null); // null para tener un absolute layout (malo)
        initComponents();
    }

    private void initComponents() {
        casilla = new JTextArea();
        casilla.setBounds(592, 95, 177, 400);
        add(casilla);

        JButton boton = new JButton("EJECUTAR");
        boton.setBounds(592, 65, 177, 20);
        add(boton);
        boton.addActionListener(this);
    }

    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        Algoritmo2 alg = new Algoritmo2();
        alg.algoritmo(casilla);
    }
    
}
```

Espero haberte ayudado.

Comment: Es la primera vez que trabajo con interfaces gráficas. Revisaré a lo largo del día su pregunta detenidamente y con la API de Java al lado. Mañana como tarde seguramente le responda. Gracias por su esfuerzo.

Comment: He probado a insertar el botón y la casilla en initComponents, como dice su código. Sí es cierto que ahora solo sale una vez todos los componentes por mucho que pulse el botón, pero tanto el botón como la casilla salen, dentro de la ventana creada para albergarlos, en y=0 y centrado en el eje X. No respeta las coordenadas de setBounds.

Comment: De hecho, he estado probando y no respeta ningún parámetro para los componentes creados dentro de initComponents

Comment: Esto hablando del proyecto original. En la adaptación que hice para esta pregunta, si reformulo siguiendo sus indicaciones (es decir, copiar su código), tampoco se respetan los parámetros de setBounds, aunque en esta ocasión la posición de los componentes es diferente

Comment: Eso depende del layout que tenga el panel. Para que `setBounds` funcione el padre debe tener un absolute layout (creo que se logra con `new JPanel(null)`). De cualquier forma no es muy recomendable colocar así los elementos porque no es *responsive*, y no es muy usado por lo mismo

Comment: No pretendo que sea responsive. De hecho, el proyecto original fija el tamaño de la ventana y no deja redimensionarla. Es para ir aprendiendo, nada más. En cuanto a lo de "new JPanel(null)", dice de ponerlo en el panel. Imagino que en el constructor Lamina2 debo pasar null a super(). Es lo único que se me ocurre.

Comment: Puede ser `super(null)` o `new Lamina2(null)` (con un constructor que delegue al del padre) o `lamina.setLayout(null)` u otra forma que se te ocurra.

Comment: super(null) funciona perfectamente, gracias. Modifica la respuesta para poder darle el visto bueno.